# How to fix issues with property does not exist on type?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular so I was following a tutorial and have the following code:

```
  //Fetching users

  getUsers(size: number =10): Observable<any>{

    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/?results=${size}`);

   }
```

The above code is for a component called user.services, this functiontries getting a api response, to use this method on another component I have the following:

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
      this.userService.getUsers(10).subscribe(
        (results: any) => {
          console.log(results);
        }
      );


  }
}
```

Since I am injecting the userService on the constructor of the users.components.ts file I don't understand why I get the error saying Property 'getUsers' does not exist on type 'UserService'

I am able to see that VSCODE also sees the function definition

[image]

what could be the issue for this?

Comment: Can you provide a StackBlitz sample?
OR please share full implementation of user service and its usage

Comment: Check if there is only one UserService class. And if possible share the code of UserService class too! Best would be a stackblitz sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think its due to not `providing the service`, you can do this in two ways

1. adding the `providedIn` in the injector decorator! which makes it available throughout the angular project! if you give 'root'

ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root', // <- changed here
})
export class TestService {
  constructor() {}

  test() {
    console.log('hello!');
  }
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-do6sfw)

2. You can add it to the `providers` array of the respective module

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [TestService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1v3b6r)